# Align concent in table cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn

I am a little stuck with my tables. I'd like to display Use-Case description and would like to align content in my table. I tried various options, but it's always messing it up. Would be great if someone could assist me here. I've been trying with `\multicolumn` as well as `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` but no luck :(

Any input is much appreciated.

What I'd like to achieve:

1. Increase the default table row to 1.5 of it's normal height
2. Vertical center the cell contents of the first row
3. Decrease indent of enumerations (or lists in general)

I've attached a render and marked it accordingly to give an idea.

[image]

Here's the minimal latex code to reprocude:

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Präambel                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Packages        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{float} %Unterdrückt das Fliessen eines Bildes wenn statt "h" "H" als float angegeben wird.
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} %Automatische Verweise mit \cref{} oder \cpageref{} auf \label{}. Bei englischer Arbeit muss "german" durch "english" ersetzt werden.
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Dokument                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{2} %Seitennummerierung ab hier

\tableofcontents{}

\begin{table} [!htbp]
%
\tablestyle[sansbold]
%
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.8\textwidth}}}
\theadstart
    \thead Bezeichner &
    \thead UC-SelectionField (Desktop) \\ 
\tbody
 Beschreiber & Das bestehende SelectionField soll so erweitert werden, dass im Dropdown, abhängig von der Eingabe, entsprechende Vorschläge zur Auswahl angezeigt werden. \\
 Akteure & Anwendungsbenutzer \\
 Vorbedingungen & Das SelectionField ist noch leer. \\
 Nachbedingung & Eine Selektion wurde durch den Anwendungsbenutzer getätigt. Die Auswahl ist im SelectionField sichtbar.Das SelectionField wird als valid angezeigt. \\
 Hauptszenario & 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer fokussiert das SelectionField.
        \item Das Dropdown erscheint, mit allen Auswahlmöglichkeiten.
        \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer tippt eine Eingabe ins Textfeld des SelectionFields.
        \item Das Dropdown filtert die Auswahlmöglichkeiten anhand der Eingabe im Textfeld des SelectionFields.
        \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wählt ein Element per Mausklick im Dropdown an.
        \item Das Textfeld des SelectionFields leert sich und das selektierte Element wird anschliessend darin angezeigt.
        \item Das Dropdown schliesst sich automatisch.
        \item Das SelectionField zeigt das ausgewählte Element an.
    \end{enumerate} \\
 Alternativszenarien & 
    \textbf{2a: Anwendungsbenutzer tippt eine nicht vorhandene Auswahlmöglichkeit ins Textfeld des SelectionFields}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Das Dropdown erscheint mit einer Hinweismeldung, dass keine passenden Auswahlmöglichkeiten zur Eingabe vorhanden sind.
        \item Das SelectionField wird als invalid markiert.
        \item Ende (Keine Auswahl getätigt.)
    \end{enumerate}
    \textbf{3a: Anwendungsbenutzer möchte das Dropdown schliessen}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer klickt ausserhalb des SelectionFields oder drückt die Taste "Escape".
        \item Das Dropdown schliesst sich.
        \item Ende (Keine Auswahl getätigt).
    \end{enumerate} \\
 Bemerkungen & - \\
 \tend
\end{tabular}
\caption{Gegenüberstellung GitLab- und JIRA Ressourcen-Modell}
\end{table} 
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Add these two packages (for example after `\usepackage{tablestyles}`)

```
\usepackage{multirow} % command \multirow
\usepackage{enumitem} % change items indent
```

(2) To vertically center the first cell use `\multirow{1.7}{*}{Beschreiber}` . The first parameter moves the text vertically.

(3) To increase the row height use, for example, `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` after    `\tablestyle[sansbold]`.

This style already applies `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}`

(4) To eliminate the items margin use `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]`

[image: a]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Präambel                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Packages        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{multirow} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{enumitem}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Dokument                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{2} %Seitennummerierung ab hier  

\begin{table} [!htbp]
    %
    \tablestyle[sansbold]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<
    %
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.8\textwidth}}}
        \theadstart
        \thead Bezeichner &
        \thead UC-SelectionField (Desktop) \\ 
        \tbody
    \multirow{1.7}{*}{Beschreiber} & Das bestehende SelectionField soll so erweitert werden, dass im Dropdown, abhängig von der Eingabe, entsprechende Vorschläge zur Auswahl angezeigt werden. \\% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Akteure & Anwendungsbenutzer \\
        Vorbedingungen & Das SelectionField ist noch leer. \\
        Nachbedingung & Eine Selektion wurde durch den Anwendungsbenutzer getätigt. Die Auswahl ist im SelectionField sichtbar.Das SelectionField wird als valid angezeigt. \\
        Hauptszenario & 
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer fokussiert das SelectionField.
            \item Das Dropdown erscheint, mit allen Auswahlmöglichkeiten.
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer tippt eine Eingabe ins Textfeld des SelectionFields.
            \item Das Dropdown filtert die Auswahlmöglichkeiten anhand der Eingabe im Textfeld des SelectionFields.
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wählt ein Element per Mausklick im Dropdown an.
            \item Das Textfeld des SelectionFields leert sich und das selektierte Element wird anschliessend darin angezeigt.
            \item Das Dropdown schliesst sich automatisch.
            \item Das SelectionField zeigt das ausgewählte Element an.
        \end{enumerate} \\
        Alternativszenarien & 
        \textbf{2a: Anwendungsbenutzer tippt eine nicht vorhandene Auswahlmöglichkeit ins Textfeld des SelectionFields}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Das Dropdown erscheint mit einer Hinweismeldung, dass keine passenden Auswahlmöglichkeiten zur Eingabe vorhanden sind.
            \item Das SelectionField wird als invalid markiert.
            \item Ende (Keine Auswahl getätigt.)
        \end{enumerate}
        \textbf{3a: Anwendungsbenutzer möchte das Dropdown schliessen}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer klickt ausserhalb des SelectionFields oder drückt die Taste "Escape".
            \item Das Dropdown schliesst sich.
            \item Ende (Keine Auswahl getätigt).
        \end{enumerate} \\
        Bemerkungen & - \\
        \tend
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Gegenüberstellung GitLab- und JIRA Ressourcen-Modell}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```